# Is there a good app for uploading podcasts to my website?

Tags: ios, podcasts

I have an old iPhone 2 (and an old 3GS, if necessary), that I'm planning to use at church for capturing sermons and uploading them to our website. I'd like something so simple that even our senior pastor can't mess it up :)

Ideally, all the pastor would need to do is:

1. Hit record when he starts preaching
2. Hit stop when he's done.

I'd like the resulting recording to then be automatically uploaded to an FTP directory on my website, from which I could write a script or something to add it to the podcast.

I don't like Cinch.FM, because it doesn't appear to let you upload to your own website, and most of its competitors seem to be the same.

Any ideas on an app that could do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [iPodcaStudio](http://ipodcastudio.com/about/). It allows your to record, edit, then upload to a server using its FTP client. It costs a dollar though.

Comment: This would be perfect, but it says "Not currently available in the U.S. store"

Answer (score 0):

I love podcasting from my iPhone and iPad.  I've used AudioBoo for a couple years because it has an RSS feed I can scrape and automatically import into my Wordpress blog.  Unfortunately, it is limited to 5 minutes and you can't add a description to AudioBoo recordings.

I prefer the VR+ app because I can record unlimited length and add a title and description.  It also has FTP upload functionality. I then use the Mobile Podcaster Wordpress plugin (http://www.mobilepodcaster.com) to automatically pull in the MP3 from the VR+ RSS feed and create a new blog post.

Now I just record on my iPad or iPhone, hit submit and it's on iTunes within a couple hours with no effort on my part.  Takes all the work out of podcasting.